# Unable to add in the text colour of my menu navbar

Tags: html, css

This should be a fairly simple thing, however no matter where I add in `color: black;` the menu items do not show, you can only see them when I click and highlight over them. Please could someone point out which class needs to `color` tag to alter the text colour to black? I have tried placing it in `.topnav` with `color: black;` but did not change anything?

Also I can't get the active class to change when I'm on a different page, seems to only stay on the Home page?

```
.topnav {
  background-color:white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

**THE MENU CODE:**

```
<!-- NAV BAR homepage-->
<nav>
  <!-- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp -->
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="index.php" class="active"><i class="fas fa-home">&nbsp; Home</i></a>
      <a href="about.php"><i class="fas fa-info-circle">&nbsp; About</i></a>
      <a href="contact.php"><i class="fas fa-envelope">&nbsp; Contact</i></a>
      <?php  
        // The below is a small 'if else' statement which depending on whether a user is logged in or not, the menu items will differ
        // If logged in, then show the logout and the dashboard item
        // If not logged in, then show the login and signup button
        if (!isset($_SESSION['studentID'])) {
          echo "<a name='login-submit' href='login.php'><i class='fas fa-sign-in-alt'>&nbsp; Login</i></a>";
          echo "<a href='signup.php'><i class='fas fa-check-square'>&nbsp; Sign Up</i></a>";
        } else if (isset($_SESSION['studentID'])) {
          echo "<a href ='dashboard.php'><i class='fas fa-tachometer-alt'>&nbsp; Dashboard</i></a> ";
          echo "<a name='logout-submit' href='scripts/logout-script.php'><i class='fas fa-sign-out-alt'>&nbsp; Logout</i></a>";
        }
      ?>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="menu2Function()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have right clicked into the console to check the styles tab:
[image: style]

This is what I see on my screen without hovering over an item in the menu:
[image: without hovering]

Then this is what I see when I hover over an item (About):
[image: Hovering over about]

Comment: You need to remove color: #f2f2f2 from .topnav a

Comment: Tried this also @MihirKumar no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `color: black` to yours `.topnav a` components and get out the text from the `fontawesome` tag. For example replace that:

```html
<i class="fas fa-envelope">&nbsp; Contact</i>
```

to that:

```html
<i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp; Contact
```

You will get something like that:

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */

.active {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}


/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}


/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Style the links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */

.topnav a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}


/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- NAV BAR homepage-->
<nav>
  <!-- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp -->
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="index.php" class="active"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>&nbsp; Home</a>
    <a href="about.php"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>&nbsp; About</a>
    <a href="contact.php"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp; Contact</a>
    <a name='login-submit' href='login.php'><i class='fas fa-sign-in-alt'></i>&nbsp; Login</a>;
    <a href='signup.php'><i class='fas fa-check-square'></i>&nbsp; Sign Up</a>;
    <a href='dashboard.php'><i class='fas fa-tachometer-alt'></i>&nbsp; Dashboard</a>;
    <a name='logout-submit' href='scripts/logout-script.php'><i class='fas fa-sign-out-alt'></i>&nbsp; Logout</a>;
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="menu2Function()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi, so I have added in `color: black;` to the class of `.topnav a` and it is still not changing. I have also wiped the cache in case that was the issue. Could it be that something else is overriding me from changing the text color?

Comment: @K.Haydock Try with `color: black !important;`

Comment: I'm afraid not, I even searched all of my CSS document in case anything else was called .topnav and that is the only thing in my stylesheet called that?

Comment: Using the `inspector` on the right element what do you see for styles ?

Comment: Yes but please be sure that you have selected the `.topnav a` component. In your screenshot it's not the case

Comment: @K.Haydock Here you have the `.topnav` selected but not the `.topnav a` ;) Just go a little further down.

Comment: @K.Haydock What do you see on your screen then ?

Comment: added screenshots for you to see my view.

Comment: Try to get out the text from the `fontawesome` tag. For example replace that `<i class="fas fa-envelope">&nbsp; Contact</i>` to that `<i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp; Contact`

Comment: That's worked Johann!!!!  :)  what on earth was causing this issue then please?

Comment: I hadn't seen it before but never wrote something inside a `<i class="fa">` element. This tag is only for the icon ;)

Comment: You are amazing, thank you so much!!! If you pop that in the answer field, I can marl you correct :-)

Answer (score 1):

For a first pitch, I would say that the color of your text is the same as the background of the navbar/body so you could try adding a `background-color: color`  to your navbar.

```
.topnav a {
 background-color: lightgray; //background-color
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color: black; //change color of the text
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
}
```

If you decide to not add a background-color you can consider changing the color of the text to any other with `color: [color]`.

Answer (score 1):

a good way to assure if the color is not being overwritten you can put "!important" after the color like the following code below

```css
.top-nav {
color:black !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in above code if you want to add background full navbar then added

`.topnav{
      background-color:hotpink;
      overflow:hidden;
     }`

image look like below

[image: Full nav menubar color]

if you want to added background only item then added below style code into

```
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    background: red;// background will be red all menu item
    }
```

image like below

[image: Red color navmenu]